# ng-bootstrap typeahead TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, typeahead, ng-bootstrap, typeerror

I would like to use the angular bootstrap typeahead [linkToTypeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) in an angular5 app.
But I keep getting the following error(s):

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at new NgbTypeahead (typeahead.js:52)
at createClass (core.js:12449)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12284)
at createViewNodes (core.js:13742)
at callViewAction (core.js:14176)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
at createViewNodes (core.js:13770)
at callViewAction (core.js:14176)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
at createViewNodes (core.js:13770)
```

and also:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
at nodeValue (core.js:11753)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NgbdTypeaheadBasic.html:9)
at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
at eval (core.js:10587)
at HTMLDocument.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
```

I copied the Simple Typeahead code from the website [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples).

My package.json file:

`{
  "name": "test-type-ahead",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-alpha.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}`

What I have tried so far:

1. reinstalled node_modules with npm -- does not help
2. Started a brand new project with the angular CLI and tried out the code there -- does not help.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 2.0.0-alpha.0 is an undocumented alpha version which AFAIK, is a preliminary version to be used with Angular 6. Use the latest stable version of ng-bootstrap: 1.1.1.

Comment: use `ng-bootstrap` :1.1 v and don't forget to use `.forRoot()` in app.module while importing the main module for ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So my Problem was solved by installing a stable version of ng-bootstrap:

so package.json file :

```
`dependencies
 ....
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
 ....
 dependencies`
```

Thanks for the quick answers to JB Nizet and Niladri

---

EDIT: Also, as @Niladri said in the comments, you need to use `forRoot()` for the modules you want to use. This is the [official documentation of version 1.1](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/1_1_maintanance) which is for Angular 5 and it is said here, but the new documentation for newer versions of angular doesn't say that, as it was changed. So keep that in mind!